# When would endianness be an issue when hashing data?

Tags: python, networking, hash, endianness, sha256

I am studying the SHA256 hash algorithm, which uses big-endian byte order. Would I actually ever have to consider endianness when using hashing algorithms? Maybe when a different endian computer runs my script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would probably never have to consider it, but I guess there would be some corner-cases where endianness would be important. Check this post for details: [Little endian data and sha 256](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269719/little-endian-data-and-sha-256)